# Adding NaoQI API to PYTHONPATH (v1.12)

Tags: ros, nao-robot, nao, nao-driver, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to set up ROS on my Nao robot.  I keep getting the error: "Please make sure that Aldebaran's NaoQI API is in your PYTHONPATH."  I found the answer below:

http://answers.ros.org/question/28814/adding-naoqi-to-the-pythonpath

and executed

PYTHONPATH=/my/path/to/naoqi-sdk-1.12-linux32/lib:${PYTHONPATH} ,

with "/my/path/to" being the path to the SDK in my system, but the error did not go away.  I am using naoqi-sdk-1.12-linux32, so is the path different for this newer version?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28902/adding-naoqi-api-to-pythonpath-(v1.12)/) by [greczek_USC](https://answers.ros.org/users/1883/greczek_usc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Put this

```
export AL_DIR=/home/naokinect/nao1.12/naoqi-sdk-1.12-linux32
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$AL_DIR/lib
export PYTHONPATH=$AL_DIR/lib:$PYTHONPATH
```

into your bashrc. Path to the lib may differ to your path. Works for me.

---

Originally posted by [SLAMnect](https://answers.ros.org/users/253/slamnect/) with karma: 58 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-04-10**:
Using NaoQI 1.12.3 this seems to be fixed and the Python API only needs to be in the PYTHONPATH, no more need for LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As SLAMnect wrote, it seems like the NaoQI Python API in version 1.12 also seems to require LD_LIBRARY_PATH set in addition to the PYTHONPATH. But I would suggest against putting the complete directory always in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH in .bashrc. There are many other libraries in this directory and it will mess up your system with conflicting versions of boost for example.

Instead, put

```
export AL_DIR=$HOME/path/to/naoqi-sdk-1.12-linux32 
export PYTHONPATH=$AL_DIR/lib:$PYTHONPATH
```

in your .bashrc and either start nao_driver with

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$AL_DIR/lib roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver.launch
```

or run

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$AL_DIR/lib
```

only in the terminal where you run nao_driver.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-03-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1